# Why pagespeed insights report shows a different page screenshot

Tags: pagespeed, webpagetest

Somehow i found pagespeed insight report showing a different page screenshot for [url](https://www.quikr.com/homes/property/residential-for-sale-in-bangalore-cid_23). Although i find the current screenshot in webpagetest [report](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190206_HX_d0507ecc452725dbb1f6d02ed833f321/). Any reason why this is different?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly because Quikr is using IP address to determine the user location, if you check the webpagetest the IP address location showing is of Mumbai(India)

> From: Mumbai, India - EC2 - Chrome - Emulated Motorola G (gen 4) - 3GFast - Mobile
>   2/6/2019, 3:38:37 PM

and since the Quikr is India based it is showing the desired result when checked in  webpagetest whereas in case of Google pagespeed insights the emulator location is mostly likely in USA so Quikr couldn't verify the user location hence when pagespeed visit the page it ask for location which you can see in the form of different screenshot in PS when compared with webpagetest.

[image]

Comment: If that would be the case, when crawled as google bot should show the same image. But it is not showing that. Screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/adr6CYu

Comment: just use some foreign proxy and you will understand what I meant. Also the SEO team knows what to show to user and what to show to search bots.